# Is there any talk about mermaids in Quran

Tags: quran, mythology

Is there anything about mermaids in Quran

Comment: If you want to know about mermaids then search google or an encyclopedia. This site is strictly for questions about Islam, not on general knowledge,

Answer (score 0):

The Quran does not say anything about mermaids. This is trivial to verify by using any search engine - for example click [here](https://www.searchtruth.com/search.php?keyword=mermaid) to use searctruth.com and you will get:

[image]

Or click [here](https://corpus.quran.com/search.jsp?q=mermaid) to search corpus.quran.com and you will get:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes, mermaids are discussed in the Qur'an. They are figures that lure men to do forbidden things. However, the existence of mermaids is not confirmed or denied by the Qur'an or the hadith. All we can say is that we are not sure and this topic is yet to investigate.

Comment: "Yes, mermaids are discussed in the Qur'an" ... where?